# How do I prove that this set is convex?

Tags: convex-optimization

How do I prove that this set is convex?
$S_2 = \{(x_1, x_2 ) : x_1x_2 ≥ 4, x_1 > 0, x_2 > 0\}$

I failed to prove that with {tx1 + (1 − t)x2 : 0 ≤ t ≤ 1}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\{(x_1,x_2):x_1x_2\geq4,x_1\ge 0,x_2\ge0\}$ is a convex set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132148/show-that-x-1-x-2x-1x-2-geq4-x-10-x-20-is-a-convex-set)

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/798111/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are in a 2-dimensional space it is not enough to test for $\{tx_1 + (1-t)x_2: 0\leq t\leq 1\}$. You need to proof that for each $(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\in S_2$ the convex hull of those two points lies inside $S_2$ as well. Let $t\in[0,1]$ be arbitrary and take a point from the convex hull:

$$
t\cdot(x_1,x_2) + (1-t)\cdot (y_1,y_2) = (tx_1+(1-t)y_1,tx_2+(1-t)y_2) =: (z_1,z_2)
$$

1. $z_1>0$ 
    $tx_1 + (1-t)y_1 > t\cdot 0 + (1-t) \cdot 0 = 0$
2. $z_2>0$ 
    $tx_2 + (1-t)y_2 > t\cdot 0 + (1-t) \cdot 0 = 0$
3. $z_1z_2 \geq 4$: This is the part where a bit calculation is necessary:
   $$(tx_1+(1-t)y_1)\cdot (tx_2+(1-t)y_2) = t^2x_1x_2 + t(1-t)(x_1y_2+x_2y_1) + (1-t)^2y_1y_2)\\
   \geq t^2\cdot 4 + (1-t)^2 \cdot 4 + t(1-t) \cdot \left(\frac{4y_2}{x_2} + \frac{4x_2}{y_2}\right) \\
   \geq4\cdot (t^2 + (1-t)^2 + 2t(1-t)) = 4 \cdot(t + (1-t))^2 =4
   $$
   The first inequality comes from the fact that $x_1x_2, y_1y_2 \geq 4$ which can be rewritten as $x_1 \geq \frac{4}{x_2}$ and $y_1\geq \frac{4}{y_2}$. The second inequality arises from the simple equation $a^2>0$ together with $x_2,y_2>0$:
   $$
   (x-y)^2 \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy \Leftrightarrow \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} \geq 2
   $$